# JQuery перекрасить строку при условии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table

Всем привет, хочу перекрасить строку в таблице с помощью JQuery и для этого я использую этот метод:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#attributes');
        $('#attributes > tbody > tr').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('td.status').text().trim() == 'approved'
        }).css('background-color', '#A9A9A9');
    });
```

Проблема в том, что почему-то строки перекрашиваются через одну, хотя должны все, вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

**Всем спасибо, проблема была вообще в другом скрипте, который относился к этой же таблице. Этот код полностью рабочий.**

Comment: Приведите весь необходимы для воспроизведения проблемы код (см. [mcve]).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, спасибо, уже решил проблему

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один метод, пройтись `each`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#attributes td.status').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == 'approved') {
   $(this).css({
    'background': '#A9A9A9'
   });
  }
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="attributes">
  <tr>
    <td class="status">approved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="status">approved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="status">hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="status">approved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="status">approved</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Думаете, поможет?

Comment: Оно то работает, только вот перекрашивает только смолбец status, а как сделать, чтобы строчку всю перекрашивало, а не только там, где значение?

Comment: @Igor думаю должно помочь, если конечно вместе сможем предугадать что не работает у Dialkord-a )))

Comment: @Dialkord в дальнейшем старайтесь показывать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример, чтобы отвечающим не гадать что у вас и какая там проблема.